# Accessing models from view in MVC 2 Timesheet application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to create a timesheet application in MVC 2, but I feel like I am still struggling to grasp the model/view relationships and all that.

The problem I have is, I want to let the user report a new time segment in a create view. But I want to have dropdownlists populated with Projects, Tasks, and Consultants from the model.

Basically the database structure looks like this:

```
(table) TimeSegments
TimeSegmentID
Hours
Date
ConsultantID (FK)
TaskID (FK)
ProjectID (FK)

(table) Projects
ProjectID
ProjectName

(table) Tasks
TaskID
TaskName

(table) Consultants
ConsultantID
ConsultantName
```

This design may be extended in future, right now I want to get basic functionality working before I complicate it further.

Now, I am passing the entire model to the create view (actually a viewmodel based on it, just to simplify some coding, but it might as well have been the entire model).

The problem is, normally when I have done similar things with a create view, I would have created a new object in the controller and passed that to the view. In this case it would have been the TimeSegment object, since it is a new time segment that should be created in the database. Then I could just submit it and update the database in the controller. However, if I only pass a new TimeSegment object to the view, I can't populate the dropdownlists with Projects, Tasks and Consultants.

And oppositely, if I only pass the entire model, how would I bind a textbox to a new TimeSegment to be updated in the database?

I feel like I need to send both a new TimeSegment object and the entire model to do this, but then I have no idea how I would access it (there's only that one "Model" to access from the view). Also, back in the controller after a submit, how would the controller know what to update?

I'm sure I'm just thoroughly confused still by the MVC way of thinking, but I would really appreciate it if someone could clarify this for me and tell me (as pedagogically as possible) what to do to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I will give it a shot.

MVC is not hard, but you do have to alter your way of thinking a bit. In MVC you have the Models (your data layer[s]), the Views and the Controllers.

Before we continue, I make the assumptions with my examples below that you are using LINQ to SQL for you data access layer (Model), and I have labeled it as `dc`.

The Controllers fetch and format the data out of the Models and hand it off to the Views to display. So lets start with your first view which would be the view to create a TimeSegment.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateTimeSegment() {
    return View(new TimeSegmentView {
        Consultants = dc.Consultants.ToList(),
        Projects = dc.Projects.ToList(),
        Tasks = dc.Tasks.ToList()
    });
}
```

This action will create a `TimeSegmentView` object and pass that to the `View` as its `Model`. Keep in mind that *this* action is decorated with `[HttpGet]`. TimeSegmentView` is a container class for the objects you need to pass to the view to create your UI and it looks like this:

```
public class TimeSegmentView {
    public IList<Consultant> Consultants { get; set; }
    public IList<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public IList<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    public TimeSegment TimeSegment { get; set; }
}
```

**NOTE:** I'm not using the TimeSegment property yet, it's further down...

In the view make sure you have it inherit from TimeSegmentView. Assuming that you're following the default MVC project structure and with me taking the liberty to add a `Views` folder into the `Models` folder your full reference would look like this:

```
<%@ Page Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<PROJECTNAME.Models.Views.TimeSegmentView>" %>
```

Now you've typed the view to that object and you can now interact with its properties. So, you can build a form such as:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    <p>
        <label>Hours</label>
        <input name="TimeSegment.Hours" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Date</label>
        <input name="TimeSegment.Date" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Consultant</label>
        <select name="TimeSegment.ConsultantID">
            <% foreach (Consultant C in Model.Consultants) { %>
            <option value="<%=C.ConsultantID%>"><%=C.ConsultantName%></option>
            <% }; %>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Project</label>
        <select name="TimeSegment.ProjectID">
            <% foreach (Project P in Model.Projects) { %>
            <option value="<%=P.ProjectID%>"><%=P.ProjectName%></option>
            <% }; %>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Task</label>
        <select name="TimeSegment.TaskID">
            <% foreach (Task T in Model.Tasks) { %>
            <option value="<%=T.TaskID%>"><%=T.TaskName%></option>
            <% }; %>
        </select>
    </p>
</form>
```

As you can see it created 3 select fields and just performed loops in each of them to build up their values based off of the model.

Now, taking a submission of this form, we'll need to get the data and add it to our database with:

```
[HttpPost]
public RedirectToRouteResult CreateTimeSegment(
    [Bind(Prefix = "TimeSegment", Include = "Hours,Date,ConsultantID,ProjectID,TaskID")] TimeSegment TimeSegment) {
    dc.TimeSegments.InsertOnSubmit(TimeSegment);
    dc.SubmitChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("EditTimeSegment", new {
        TimeSegmentID = TimeSegment.TimeSegmentID
    });
}
```

Okay, first notice that I've named the action the same, but this one has an `[HttpPost]` decoration. I'm telling the action that I'm sending it a `TimeSegment` object and that I want it to bind the properties in the Include clause (this is mostly for security and validation). I then take the `TimeSegment` object I've passed in, add it to the data context, submit the changes and redirect. In this case I'm redirecting to another action to edit the object I just created passing in the new `TimeSegmentID`. You can redirect to what ever, this just felt appropriate to me...

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EditTimeSegment(
    int TimeSegmentID) {
    return View(new TimeSegmentView {
        Consultants = dc.Consultants.ToList(),
        Projects = dc.Projects.ToList(),
        Tasks = dc.Tasks.ToList(),
        TimeSegment = dc.TimeSegments.Single(t => t.TimeSegmentID == TimeSegmentID)
    });
}
```

In the edit action your doing the same thing as in the create action by building a new `TimeSegmentView` object and passing it to the view. The key difference here is that you're now populating the `TimeSegment` property. Your form would look something like this (shortened from above):

```
<form action="/<%=Model.TimeSegment.TimeSegmentID%>" method="post">
    <p>
        <label>Hours</label>
        <input name="TimeSegment.Hours" value="<%=Model.TimeSegment.Hours%>" />
    </p>
</form>
```

And your receiving action on the controller would look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public RedirectToRouteResult EditTimeSegment(
    int TimeSegmentID) {
    TimeSegment TS = dc.TimeSegments.Single(t => t.TimeSegmentID == TimeSegmentID);

    TryUpdateModel<TimeSegment>(TS, "TimeSegment", new string[5] {
        "Hours", "Date", "ConsultantID", "ProjectID", "TaskID"
    });

    dc.SubmitChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("EditTimeSegment", new {
        TimeSegmentID = TimeSegment.TimeSegmentID
    });
}
```

Lastly, if you want to display a list of TimeSegments you can do something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ListTimeSegments() {
    return View(new TimeSegmentsView {
        TimeSegments = dc.TimeSegments.ToList()
    });
}
```

And `TimeSegmentsView` looks like this:

```
public class TimeSegmentsView {
    public IList<TimeSegment> TimeSegments { get; set; }
}
```

And in the `View` you'd want to do this:

```
<table>
    <% foreach (TimeSegment TS in Model.TimeSegments) { %>
    <tr>
        <td><%=TS.Hours%></td>
        <td><%=TS.Date%></td>
        <td><%=TS.Project.ProjectName%></td>
        <td><%=TS.Consultant.ConsultantName%></td>
        <td><%=TS.Task.TaskName%></td>
    </tr>
    <% }; %>
</table>
```

I hope this is enough to give you a start. It's by no means complete, but its 5 AM and I haven't slept yet, so this will have to do for now (from me). Feel free to name your actions what you want, you don't have to stick to my naming conventions.

I would suggest however that you change the naming of the properties of your tables. For example when your writing the expressions like in the table above you'll have to do `TS.Project.ProjectName` and that's redundant. You're already accessing the `Project` property of `TS` through their relationship so you know you're only going to work with a `Project`. This then makes `ProjectName` a pointless blob of text re-describing the object your working with. Instead just use `Name`, and turn your expression to `TS.Project.Name`.

Anyway, just a suggestion, do what you like better. I'm passing out, so good night and happy Thanksgiving!

**UPDATE**

The process with collections is essentially the same as far as the controller side is conserned. It's the client side and the JavaScript that's more difficult to get going, so I'll assume that you have something established on that end.

So, here's how the controller would work. You pass in an array of TimeSegment and the model binder is smart enough to figure it out through the *Prefix* of your form elements.

```
<form action="/<%=Model.TimeSegment.TimeSegmentID%>" method="post">
    <p>
        <label>Hours</label>
        <input name="TimeSegment[0].Hours" />
        <!-- Notice the array in the prefix -->
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Hours</label>
        <input name="TimeSegment[1].Hours" />
        <!-- Notice the array in the prefix -->
    </p>
</form>
```

And the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public RedirectToRouteResult CreateTimeSegments(
    [Bind(Prefix = "TimeSegment", Include = "Hours,Date,ConsultantID,ProjectID,TaskID")] TimeSegment[] TimeSegments) {
    dc.TimeSegments.InsertAllOnSubmit(TimeSegments);
    dc.SubmitChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("ListTimeSegments");
}
```

And that's it. Of course you'll want to validate or do other stuff before sending to the database, but that's roughly all there is to it.

**UPDATE 2**

I believe you can do an `IList<TimeSegment>` instead of `TimeSegment[]` without issues, but as far as if it's better, that's up for debate. The way I look at it the browser still sends a *virtual* array to the server so having the action receive an array feels natural, but its up to you what you want to use.

So, a generic list action would look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public RedirectToRouteResult CreateTimeSegments(
    [Bind(Prefix = "TimeSegment", Include = "Hours,Date,ConsultantID,ProjectID,TaskID")] IList<TimeSegment> TimeSegments) {
    dc.TimeSegments.InsertAllOnSubmit(TimeSegments);
    dc.SubmitChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("ListTimeSegments");
}
```

Keep in mind that I haven't used this (meaning the IList) before so I can't guarantee it will work, just speculating...

**UPDATE 3**

About what you want to do with the `Consultant`, it sound a lot like what I do with Cookies. I have a `BaseView` class which is the type used by the Site.Master and then all other views extend from it. In the `BaseView` I have a Cookie property which is always populated by each controller action. I then use that property to get the id of the currently authorized user.

So, in code it looks like this (using examples from one of my apps):

```
public class BaseView {
    // Don't confuse with an HttpCookie, this is an object in my database...
    public Cookie Cookie { get; set;}
}

public class EmployeeView : BaseView {
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

And with this, say I want to add a note to an employee, my form would look like this where I pass in a hidden field which is where your `ConsultantID` comes into play.

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="Note.AuthorId" value="<%=Model.Cookie.EmployeeId%>" />
    <!-- other fields -->
</form>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, awesome answer! Could I just ask you also as a follow-up: how would I handle adding several time segments at a time for a whole week? A lot of timesheet applications often have several dropdown lists stacked above one another, to choose project etc, and then a table with week days, so that I can add e.g. projectA 2 hrs, projectB 6 hrs for Monday, projectA 5hrs, projectB 2 hrs for Tuesday, etc. How would I submit this to the controller? It wouldn't know which input field hours referred to what timesegment? A collection somehow? I have no idea...

Comment: I've added an update to my answer about how to work with a collection. Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok, not quite sure I get it... What would the httpget action method look like then? Do I create an array with a set number of items? And if so, how can the view do this: /<%=Model.TimeSegment.TimeSegmentID%> ? Maybe I'm missing something, but if the model is an array I don't see how I can access a TimeSegment without an index or something? I would really appreciate it if you could take the time to just spell out the httpget method and the question about the index... Thanks!

Comment: And I should still send in a TimeSegmentView object that contains this new array or what? Because I will still need access to the Projects, Tasks, etc for the dropdown lists... BTW, could I use a generic List instead of array? If so, could you use that in the example?

Comment: Yet another question :-) What does the action attribute in the form do, pass an ID parameter? Is that received by the action method? And if so, how does it save all the time segments? Sorry if I'm being dim about all this :-)

Comment: For the `[HttpGet]` which I assume you mean listing out a collection of `TimeSegment`, I wrote one above called `ListTimeSegment` which passes in a `TimeSegmentsView` which contains a collection of `TimeSegment`. The view can do `<%=Model.TimeSegment.TimeSegmentID%>` because the view was strong-typed against the `TimeSegmentView` or `TimeSegmentsView` object. Thus we can interact with its properties directly through `Model`. On your generic list question, look at the update to my update above.

Comment: I'm not sure if you've looked at the videos for MVC, but a good starter video is here: http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/matthijs/aspnet-mvc-2-basics-introduction-by-scott-hanselman. It goes through a complete project from scratch and may very well answer all of your questions on how to work with the Views, the Models and the Controllers. I highly recommend that you watch it.

Comment: Oups, missed your 3rd question... Yes and No. Yes, the *form action* is passing in the Id to the *controller action*, but this is only on the edit action because you are now working with a specific `TimeSegment`. The controller action uses the Id to fetch the object out of the database so it can pass it to the `TryUpdateModel<T>` so it can be updated with the new values from the form post and then it submits the changes to the db. So, no, it doesn't have anything to do when you're creating single or multiple `TimeSegment`s.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Unfortunately, the <form action="/<%=Model.TimeSegment.TimeSegmentID%>" method="post"> won't work. The compiler complains, as I suspected, about the TimeSegment part. But maybe I misunderstood how to construct the model object? I may have to try to work this out myself after learning MVC a bit more... I wonder if you could suggest how I could remove the Consultant bit from the View though, because on second thoughts I will take this from the login name, so I want to set it in the post action method. But now it's in the parameters and all... Marking this as answer now! Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like your model is not being setup properly. Anyway, I've added another update about your question with the consultant. And definitely watch the videos at www.asp.net/mvc. They can explain far better than me just posting bits and pieces. You'll be able to see how everything flows into each other and you'll understand better. Good luck!